# How to test emit event on ngSubmit within component subscribe method

Tags: jasmine, emit

On form submit getUsers() is called and if success message is received, the received data is emitted to the parent component.

**child html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="getUsers()">
</form>
```

**child component**

```
getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
     if(users.status=="Success"{
      this.listOfUsers = users;
      this.user.emit(this.listOfUsers);
      this.nextTab.emit(true);
     }
    });
  }
```

i have written the test case to check emit event as follows

```
it('should emit data on success', () => {
    spyOn(component.user,'emit');
    component.getUsers();
    expect(component.user.emit).toHaveBeenCalled(); // fails as never called what i am doing wrong
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that `userService.getUsers` returns an observable.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
it('should emit data on success', () => {
    // mock userService.getUsers to return { status: 'Success' } to go inside of the if block
    spyOn(userService, 'getUsers').and.returnValue(of({ status: 'Success' }));
    spyOn(component.user,'emit');
    component.getUsers();
    expect(component.user.emit).toHaveBeenCalled(); // fails as never called what i am doing wrong
  });
```

**Edit**

To actually test `ngSubmit`, I would use `triggerEventHandler`. You can do some research on it.

```
const form = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
// The 2nd argument is what you would like the $event value to be.
// In our case, null is fine.
form.triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);
```

Doing the above will call `getUsers`.

Comment: This is testing `getUsers`, not `ngSubmit`. While similar, there are fundamental differences.

Comment: Ok, check out my edit, I present a way in how to test `ngSubmit`. You can also test it by clicking the submit button of the form as well I assume.